# How to calculate this sum of inverses?

Tags: summation, inverse, substitution

I want to calculate this sum:

$$-m u \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{M+im}$$

I tried a substitution like this:

$$-m u \sum_{k=M+m}^{M+Nm} \frac1k$$

But it seems to have become complicated!

Does anyone have an idea how to evaluate the sum?

Comment: You need something called harmoic numbers.

Comment: Yes, there is no closed formula for your sum, see the [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1896995) of @Claude Leibovici

Answer (score 1):

As Zack Ni commented, this corresponds to [generalized harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{M+im}=\frac 1m\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{\frac Mm+i} =\frac 1m\left({H_{\frac{M}{m}+N}-H_{\frac{M}{m}}}\right)$$